# How to animate UIView layer background color with Facebook Pop Animation Framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation, facebook-pop

Facebook just open sourced their awesome **POP animation** framework which is built from **Core Animation**, and I can't figure out how to animate a layers background color.

Here's my code:

```
POPBasicAnimation *colorAnimation = [POPBasicAnimation animation];
colorAnimation.property = [POPAnimatableProperty propertyWithName:kPOPViewBackgroundColor];

if (_pressed)
{
    colorAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
}
else
{
    colorAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
}

[_button pop_addAnimation:colorAnimation forKey:@"colorAnimation"];
```

The `.toValue` should only accept `NSNumber` or `NSValue` but I can't figure out how to pass in a color to animate as the `.toValue`.

Anyone out there know?

Comment: That code seems to work properly for me. What's not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so I solved it with this code hope it helps. I just changed POPBasicAnimation to POPSpringAnimation. Here's the code

```
POPSpringAnimation *colorAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animation];
colorAnimation.property = [POPAnimatableProperty propertyWithName:kPOPViewBackgroundColor];

if (clic)
{
    colorAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
}
else
{
    colorAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
}

[imagen pop_addAnimation:colorAnimation forKey:@"colorAnimation"];
```

Comment: Going to try this now. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Works great. Don't know why the basic animation won't accept it because when I use normal CABasicAnimation it works fine. Must be an error on their end.

Answer (score 2):

You can animate background color change on every view with POP.

**Example with POPBasicAnimation**

```
POPBasicAnimation *basicAnimation = [POPBasicAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPViewBackgroundColor];
basicAnimation.toValue = [UIColor greenColor];

[_yourView pop_addAnimation:basicAnimation forKey:@"backgroundColorChange"];
```

**Example with POPSpringAnimation**

```
POPSpringAnimation *springAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPViewBackgroundColor];
springAnimation.toValue = [UIColor greenColor];

[_yourView pop_addAnimation:springAnimation forKey:@"backgroundColorChange"];
```